# How to use datetime-local type in html table?

Tags: html, html-table

In a html table I will be displaying datetime in a column.

In forms I use type="datetime-local" to get it formatted in AM/PM.

I use `<input type="datetime-local">"2018-10-22T13:38:58"</input>`
The above code gets displayed in the UI as `12/10/2015,11:11 AM`

How to get the equivalent of datetime-local  in html table?
in table `<td> "2018-10-22T13:38:58"</td>`
*How should I mention the type?*

p.s: Please help me format and edit the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use moment js to achieve a formatting in your table. I've added a code snippet for preview.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var date = $('#date').val();
  var table = "<table>";
  table += "<tr><th>Date</th></tr>";
  table += "<tr><td>" + moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY H:mm')  + "</td></tr>";
  table += "</table>";
  $('#table-container').append(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date" type="datetime-local" value="2018-06-12T19:30" />
<div id="table-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method of native `Date` module. Based on the framework you're using you can make use of this function on frontend. Also, it would be better if you can manipulate the date on backend and just display whatever comes to frontend.

```js
console.log(new Date('2018-10-22T13:38:58').toLocaleString()); // Gives you 10/22/2018, 1:38:58 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

try this format:

```
$originalDate = "2018-10-22T13:38:58";
$newDate = date("d/m/Y,h:i A", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found no simple way to do that in view side.
Ended up sending the date in appropriate format from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I used in a similar situation a disabled input field for getting the right user-side data format in the table.

```
<tr>
   <td>
       <input class='tdlike' type="datetime-local" value="02/02/2020 02:02" disabled>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the css I mocked the style of a normal table cell:

```
.tdlike {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: 145px;
}
```

The only disadvantage is that I did not find any way to wrap the date, it behaves just like one single word.